# Displaying content on top of video background

Tags: css, html, html5-video

I have problem displaying content on top of video background. I set correct z-indexes for both background video and divs that should appear on top of it, but it doesnt work. What should I do to display content on top of the video?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/video.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name=”description” content=”” />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="button">HELLO</div>
    </div>

    <video id="video_background" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted" volume="0"> 
    <source src="img/splash.webm" type="video/webm"> 
    <source src="img/splash.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
    <source src="img/splash.ogv" type="video/ogg ogv"; codecs="theora, vorbis"/> Video not supported </video>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 20;
}

.button {
    z-index: 20;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

#video_background {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -1000;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Solution to content on top of video background:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N7rd4/

Edit:
Besides embedding another video I did not have to change any of your css code, so its seems that you already had it working. Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Yeah, thanks and sorry. I had it working all the time. It was just the default font size of "Hello" that I couldn't see and thought that something didn't work :)